# What would be the best way to format JSON data consumed by a SPA?

Tags: json, angular, reactjs, architecture

I'm working with a friend on a single page application (in React, but I believe that the framework doesn't really matter, the same question applies to Angular as well).

There is a database with 2 tables:

- Feature
- Car

Both tables are connected in the database with many-to-many relation.

We differ in how we should pass the data from the backend to the frontend (more precisely, CarManagementComponent that will let user work on cars/features (edit/update/delete etc)). We want to have ability to perform several actions before, actually, sending a request back to the backend to update the database so that the user has desktop application-like interface experience.

Please, keep in mind that there are more tables in the database but for the example's simplicity, we're talking here only about 2 of them.

1) My approach:

```
{
    "Features": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Price": 3000,
            "Name": "led lights",
            "Color": "transparent",
            "Brand": "Valeo",
            "Guarantee": 12
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Price": 1000,
            "Name": "air conditioning",
            "Color": "",
            "Brand": "Bosch",
            "Guarantee": 12
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Price": 600,
            "Name": "tinted windows",
            "Color": "",
            "Brand": "Bosch",
            "Guarantee": 36
        }
    ],
    "Cars": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "Ford Mustang GT",
            "Weight": 2210,
            "Features":[
                {
                    "Id": 0, // id of many-to-many relations record
                    "FeatureId": 2
                },
                {
                    "Id": 1, // id of many-to-many relations record
                    "FeatureId": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Volkswagen Arteon",
            "Weight": 1650,
            "Features":[
                {
                    "Id": 2, // id of many-to-many relations record
                    "FeatureId": 2
                }
            ]
        }         
    ]
}
```

2) My friend's approach:

```
{
    "Cars": [
        {
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "Ford Mustang GT",
            "Weight": 2210,
            "Features": [
                {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Price": 1000,
                    "Name": "air conditioning",
                    "Color": "",
                    "Brand": "Bosch",
                    "Guarantee": 12
                },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "Price": 600,
                    "Name": "tinted windows",
                    "Color": "",
                    "Brand": "Bosch",
                    "Guarantee": 36
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Volkswagen Arteon",
            "Weight": 1650,
            "Features": [
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "Price": 600,
                    "Name": "tinted windows",
                    "Color": "",
                    "Brand": "Bosch",
                    "Guarantee": 36
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I belive that the 1st approach is better because:

- it weighs less (no data redundancy)
- it would be easier to convert such data into object-oriented structure
- eg. we are able to see all Feature records (in 2nd approach, we'd only see records that are being connected with Cars and another backend request would be needed)
- eg. unlike the 2nd approach, we're able to obtain all the needed data in just 1 request (less problems with synchronization) and we could be saving modified data in a single request as well

My friend says 2nd approach is better because:

- it'd be easier to achieve that using ORM (hibernate)
- he's never seen 1st approach in his life (which could lead to a conclusion, that it's being done in a wrong way)

What do you think? Which solution is better? Maybe both of them in some areas? Maybe there's a 3rd solution we didn't think of yet?

Comment: It will depend on your specific criteria. It doesn't matter what we think; if the two of you are working together, *you have to agree*. If there are concrete criteria (does response size actually matter?) then experiment and test against them.

Comment: I prefer approach #1 for the reasons you outlined. #1's data model easily supports a select list for features where you present all available features and the user selects which features apply to a given car from a list. You can support that with the second approach but I don't love the idea of deep copying your feature objects to your car objects every time a feature is added/removed from a car. I think #1 also encourages reusability (e.g. you can use the `getAllFeatures` route later to create a feature admin screen, etc.).

Comment: I prefer normalized json data which is approach 1 if you are using some sort of entity store for statement management. Otherwise approach 2 which you don't have to deal with mapping data with featureIds on javascript side. Either approach works, as jonrsharpe said you both have to agree to which approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say the approach I mostly like is yours for 2 main reasons:

1. Keeping in mind that data duplication is bad in an HTTP request, your approach is avoiding it.
2. You let the `FeatureId` inside the car object and it is enough to get the feature in an efficient performance O(N).

To make it even better, you could change your feature structure to this:

```
"Features": {
       0: { // <- If the id is unique, you can use it as a key.
            "Id": 0,
            "Price": 3000,
            "Name": "led lights",
            "Color": "transparent",
            "Brand": "Valeo",
            "Guarantee": 12
        },
        1: {
            "Id": 1,
            "Price": 1000,
            "Name": "air conditioning",
            "Color": "",
            "Brand": "Bosch",
            "Guarantee": 12
        },
        2: {
            "Id": 2,
            "Price": 600,
            "Name": "tinted windows",
            "Color": "",
            "Brand": "Bosch",
            "Guarantee": 36
        }
    },
```

This way, you can get the Feature in O(1).